# Requeue message in MassTransit without triggering retry policy

Tags: .net, microservices, domain-driven-design, amazon-sqs, masstransit

**Question**: Can I requeue message without triggering retry policy in MassTransit?

**For more context read bellow**

**General structure**:
we have two entities `SaleOrder` and `SaleReturnOrder` in a microservice let's call it **Sales API**. Each of them has its own succeeded event `SaleOrderSuceeded` and `SaleReturnOrderSucceeded` which are published based on domain event into SQS by MassTransit and later consumed by second microservice, **Inventory API**.

**Problem**:
As expected there is much more `SaleOrderSuceeded` events than `SaleReturnOrderSucceeded` which means `SaleOrderSuceeded` event consumer has to handle more messages and
as a result it's slower than `SaleReturnOrderSucceeded` consumer, because of that in some cases Inventory API passes transaction and adds sold quantity back to inventory before it got handled by `SaleOrderSuceeded` event consumer and actually got subtracted from inventory, as a result this case creates more problems later in the flow.

**My solution**:
My solution is to check whether or not sale order has already subtracted it's quantity from inventory and than handle `SaleReturnOrderSucceeded` event, otherwise throw a custom error and wait for message to come back later. But it affects retry policy and the message is going to be returned only as many times as retry policy accepts to.. my question is, could I somehow requeue message without triggering retry policy?

I'll accept any suggestions to handle the validation in different way as well

Comment: are SaleOrderSuceeded event and SaleReturnOrderSucceeded event supposed to fire in order? like trigger SaleOrderSuceeded  and then SaleReturnOrderSucceeded .

Comment: Since these events are related, you should use a saga to collect the events and subsequently do something once the related events have all been collected by the saga. There is [a sample](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-Batch) showing one way to deal with it.

Comment: @RouzbehZarandi yes but not always, only if user returns the sold item in that case the SaleReturnOrderSucceeded is being called

Comment: @ChrisPatterson yes sagas where one of the solutions in my mind but I was kind of avoiding it as I'm pretty new to them and it's gonna need a lot of things to be changed in production ready application, but  structurally it seems better decision. As I know saga saves the state of the event and based on its state lets incoming messages go through or not, my question would be if `SaleOrderSuceeded` event has not finished taking inventory and `SaleReturnOrderSucceeded` event is called  will the event just get blocked or will it be requeued to be checked later